# Windows Form DLL application

Tags: .net, dll

I have an application that I turned into a dll so it could easily be called from other applications.  I like to have a version number displayed to make sure the user is using the most current version of an application.  The version displayed using My.Application.Info.Version.Major & "." & My.Application.Info.Version.Minor & "." & My.Application.Info.Version.Build & "." & My.Application.Info.Version.Revision corresponds to the calling application rather than the dll.  When I call the DLL I want to be able to get the dll version.  Is there a way to do it without hardcoding it?

Thanks

Comment: That's because you use My.Application.  Consider using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Version instead.  It isn't otherwise clear if you want the [AssemblyVersion] or the [AssemblyFileVersion].

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to hit the assembly version.

[MSDN Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx)

Example :

```
    Dim assemName As AssemblyName = assem.GetName()
    Console.WriteLine(vbLf + "Name: {0}", assemName.Name)
    Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}.{1}", assemName.Version.Major, _
        assemName.Version.Minor)
```

Extracted from the link above